# sizing fx futures trades by targeting volatility

Tags: volatility, portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, futures, fx

If I lever up a JPY/USD futures with a 6% volatility/contract 2x to meet my 12% volatility target, how many contracts should I buy per $100,000 I have in liquidity? How do I size my position based on how much money I have?

Comment: One futures contract delivers 12,500,000 Yen, that's equivalent to about 113,000 USD. So if you have 100,000 USD in your account with 1 contract you already have 1.13 leverage, with 2 contracts 2.26 leverage, etc. (These calculations are approximate).

Comment: Understood, thank you! How would I do this using Eurodollar futures?